# Transform/Convert Scientific Notation [From Varchar to Decimal/Numeric] in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point, amazon-redshift

I have a table where one of columns carries values as below. The datatype of the column is in **VARCHAR**. Now, for the sake of customer experience, I have to convert the below values to actual non-scientific notation[refer RESULT]. Please help me achieve this.

Input Values:

```
1.1706260317772036d-3
3.0820440115884856d-4
5.584098106752352d-4
6.477217523714287d-4
3.897560962029404d-4
0
```

RESULT

```
0.0011706260317772036
0.00030820440115884856
0.0005584098106752352
0.0006477217523714287
0.0003897560962029404
0
```

I tried below of these but dint help.

```
select CAST(CAST('3.8761442700897326d-4'  AS FLOAT) AS bigint)

SELECT CAST('3.8761442700897326d-4' as REAL)
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Numeric Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html) - `E`, not `D` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You could just phrase this as:

```
select '3.8761442700897326d-4' + 0
```

I am unsure about the results you want; you have `d` in your strings, but the results look like you want `e`. You might need to replace before converting:

```
select replace('3.8761442700897326d-4', 'd', 'e') + 0
```

Comment: I have given by expectation in RESULT section... this `select '3.8761442700897326d-4' + 0` dint help. I have to do some conversion?

Comment: @user3624000: see the second part of my answer.

Comment: this is not working in redshift... sorry, I missed to update this. this just results as "3.8761442700897326e-40"

Comment: @user3624000: your question started as a MySQL question, and 3 answers were posted accordingly. Redshift is a different database, so, likely, none of these 3 answers will work. Your edit basically invalidates all existing answers. I can only recommend asking a new question, with the proper tag from the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE(str,'d', 'e') + 0
```

or, in numeric context, simply

```
REPLACE(str,'d', 'e')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1526523bf9f1e23f58d33746865e3429)

Comment: this is not working in redshift... sorry, I missed to update this. this just results as "3.8761442700897326e-40"

Comment: @user3624000 Amazon RedShift uses `E` too for scientific notation ([Integer and floating-point literals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_numeric_literals201.html)) and `+` for numeric operations only ([Compound expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_compound_expressions.html)), and [REPLACE function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REPLACE.html) has the same syntax. If `+` sign causes string concatenation then you access to RedShift, but your code is **NOT** SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that the `d` is really an `e`, which is standard for the exponent for a real number.  You can use `replace()` to change it, if you need to.

You could convert to a `float`:

```
select CAST('3.8761442700897326e-4'  AS float)
```

This does not do what you want, because a `float` is not big enough.

```
select CAST('3.8761442700897326e-4'  AS double)
```

This does what you want.  However, it is limited on the number of decimal places.  I recommend storing the value as a `decimal` rather than `double`, but that is another matter.

However, converting to a `double` (or `float`) is subject to changing the lowest order digits. If you want to preserve everything, you want to get the value to a `decimal()` as quickly as possible, and then do arithmetic:

```
select cast(left(val, 18) as decimal(38, 16)) * power(10, right(val, 2)) as x
from (select '3.8761442700897326e-4' as val) x
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7ebb2e45cc842a8c1938a71e0d069d7) is a db<>fiddle.